# Disabled Buttons in CSS?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to get a button which looks exactly the same whether it is enabled or disabled, but whenever I disable the button it seems to ignore any font styles I have set. This seems to be the case in IE but not other browsers.

So does anybody know the CSS to change a disabled button so that the font is not embossed?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

[Edit]
The CSS is as follows:

```
.Button
{
    background-color:#332F27;
    border-bottom-color:#1B1B1B;
    border-top-color:#3B3B3B;
    border-left-color:#3B3B3B;
    border-right-color:#0C0C0C; 
    color:Black;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

The button has the attribute Class="Button"
[/Edit]

Comment: Can you provide the css for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are changing the disabled property of the button then you won't be able to get the feel and look of a normal button with CSS which will work in all browsers.

The easiest way is to ***add another button with no click event attached to it*** and set this button's display to inline and hide the original one.

If you still want to use CSS for this you can refer this link.

[Styling disabled form controls with CSS](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/disabled/#list)

Comment: Not sure I'm following your answer - my CSS works fine in Chrome, just not IE.  I don't see why I can't change the look and feel of the button?

Comment: I've looked at the link just now - thought it looked promising, but the text is still embossed.

The CSS I'm using is:
.Button
{
 background-color:#332F27;
 border-bottom-color:#1B1B1B;
 border-top-color:#3B3B3B;
 border-left-color:#3B3B3B;
 border-right-color:#0C0C0C; 
 color:Black;
 font-style:normal;
}

The button is disabled and has Class="Button"

Comment: Why don't you use another button?

Comment: I'll think about using another button, but it doesn't feel like a very clean solution... Would it cause a postback if there was no click event?

Comment: I think it might be difficult to achieve this with css. No it won't cause a postback without a click event.

Comment: A nice way with jquery to have no click event is to use mousedown(): $("#disabledBtn").mousedown(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
});

Answer (score 0):

```
//You use this css it helps u
font-weight: bold;
    border-right: #3C8FD1 1px solid;
    border-top: #3C8FD1 1px solid;
    border-left: #3C8FD1 1px solid;
    border-bottom: #3C8FD1 1px solid;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #045FA7;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-image: url(../App_Images/cssbuttonbg.gif);
    line-height: 14px;
```