# JQuery Enable / Disable Submit Button in IE7

Tags: jquery, submit, internet-explorer-7

I am using the following code to disable the submit button

```
$("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

And this code to re-enable it:

```
$("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");
```

It works fine on all browsers I've tried except Internet Explorer 7. IE7 will disable the button fine, but when it is re-enabled, the button still *looks* disabled.

This button is enabled and clickable in spite of the cursor and gray color:

[image: IE7 enabled button with disabled appearance]

(A colleague had the same trouble with IE8, but I could not reproduce it.)

I have a workaround in place that does the job, but its ugly. I have two buttons, one disabled, one not. To start, I show the disabled one and hide the enabled button.

```
$("input[type='submit']:first").css("display","inline"); //show disabled
$("input[type='submit']:last").css("display","none");    //hide enabled
...
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value=" Sign In " tabindex=3 disabled>
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value=" Sign In " tabindex=3 >
```

When my "if" conditions are met, I hide the disabled submit and show the enabled one.

**Is there a more elegant CSS or JQ based solution to this problem?**

Comment: Your solution may actually be the optimal one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068568/disabled-buttons-in-css

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("input[type='submit']").prop("disabled", false);
```

Comment: You were absolutely right. I thought .removeProp() was the right way to go, but according to the JQuery documentation "The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method. The .val() method should be used for getting and setting value. Important: the .removeProp() method should not be used to set these properties to false. Once a native property is removed, it cannot be added again."

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", "");
```

or

```
$("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", false);
```

Comment: That is where I started originally. Unfortunately, both of those are supported on even fewer (older) browsers because the disabled attribute technically does not take any arguments.

Answer (score 1):

@Burak - That works very well (John Resig does mention about it of using .prop() instead of .attr() for this specific case). I also tried the `submitbutton.prop("disabled", false);` and `submitbutton.prop("disabled", true);` so that would enable and disable on IE 7/6 as well.